# Leap Motion Listener onFrame is Skipping/Ignoring Code

Tags: java, listener, leap-motion

I am developing a custom gesture creation application for Leap in Java. In the onFrame function code is being executed up to a point and the rest of the code is skipped.

The code for onFrame is below:

```
public void onFrame(Controller controller) {
    Frame frame = controller.frame();
    if (recordableFrame(frame, minRecordingVelocity)){

        /*
         * If this is the first frame in a gesture, we clean up some running         values
         */
        if (!recording) { 
            recording = true; 
            frameCount = 0;
        }

        frameCount++;
        System.out.println("in frame... " + Integer.toString(frameCount));
        recordFrame(frame);
        System.out.println("Recording Frame...");
    }    
}
```

Everything works fine, until the "recordFrame(frame) function is called. This function and any code in onFrame after this function is ignored/not executed. Instead of skipping frames, I seem to be skipping code.

The code for recordFrame is below:

```
/**
 * This function is called for each frame during gesture recording, 
 * and it is responsible for adding values in frames using the provided 
 * recordPoint function (which accepts a Vector).
 */
public void recordFrame(Frame frame) {
    HandList hands = frame.hands();
    int handCount = hands.count();

    Hand hand; 
    Finger finger; 
    FingerList fingers; 
    int fingerCount;

    int l = handCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {   //for each hand in the frame
        hand = hands.get(i);

        recordPoint(hand.stabilizedPalmPosition()); //record the palm position

        fingers = hand.fingers();
        fingerCount = fingers.count();

        int k = fingerCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {  //for each finger in the hand
            finger = fingers.get(j);
            recordPoint(finger.stabilizedTipPosition();//record fingertip position.
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Recording Frame...");
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you comment out whatever the recordPoint() function is doing?

Answer (score 1):

From Leap Motion forum:

"I found the issue. In the gesture class I declare ArrayList but never initialize it with = new ArrayList(); (weird that it didn't throw a compiler error)

Once I did that everything worked fine. I've now got it working and running."

https://community.leapmotion.com/t/listener-onframe-is-skipping-code/3108/7